# Why the bracket is not evaluated first in this Java program?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String text = "GOOD ";
        text = text + (text = "LUCK ");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

According to operator precedence, the bracket should be evaluated first which would make the reference *text* to start pointing to the String "LUCK". Further it would concatenate with the same reference *text* and finally it should have printed "LUCK LUCK".

But it actually prints "GOOD LUCK". Can someone please explain, why is it so?

Comment: Expression are evaluated left to right. The `text` on the left of the `+` is evaluated before the part on the right of `+`.

Comment: "According to operator precedence, the bracket should be evaluated first" - no, that's not true. The LHS of the + operator is always evaluated before the RHS.

Comment: The meaning of the operator precedence here is that the assignment happens before the +. Nothing to do with evaluation order of the operands.